# Does std::unique invalidate vector iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

For this code:

```
std::vector<int> v = {...};
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

// Does this work?
std::size_t unique_count = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.cbegin();
```

In the last line, I think since `std::unique` just moves stuffs around inside the vector and does not insert anything into it, no iterators should be invalidated, and so the way I'm calculating `unique_count` should be correct. But I want to make sure that is the case. Is it?

Comment: No, it won't. It can't even access the container because you're just passing 2 iterators to it.

Comment: @songyuanyao So, `unique_count` is correct. Right?

Comment: Yes it'll be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::unique` is an algorithm. All stl algorithms operate on ranges, not containers.

Although the algorithm may swap element contents, the iterators to those elements remain unchanged.

This is a guarantee.

If it were not, then this could not work:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{

  auto unique_size = [](auto&& container)
  {
    std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
    return std::unique(std::begin(container), std::end(container)) - std::cbegin(container);
  };

  std::cout << unique_size(std::vector<int> {6,5,4,4,3,2,1}) << std::endl;
  std::cout << unique_size(std::array<int,7> {6,5,4,4,3,2,1}) << std::endl;
  int x[] = {6,5,4,4,3,2,1};
  std::cout << unique_size(x) << std::endl;

    // Does this work? yes.
}
```

mandated output:

```
6
6
6
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique` return an iterator to one position past the last 'unique' element in the container.

```
auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Then the range [`last`, `v.end()`) contains whatever, you can't rely on `v.cbegin()`. Instead:

```
auto unique_count = std::distance(v.begin(), last);
```

will do the trick.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

Comment: What do you mean I can't rely on `v.cbegin()`?

Comment: sorry, I meant content is lost from [last, end()]. I would use std::distance instead of making the difference manually.

Comment: Basically `std::distance` will do the same thing with `last - v.begin()` here.

Comment: C++ algorithm NEVER delete any elements from the container. This is the rule.

Comment: @songyuanyao For generic code, yes @JonathanMULLER is right `std::distance` would be a better choice. But since vector iterators are `RandomAccessIterator`s, in this specific case it makes no difference than `last - v.cbegin()`.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Yes, this should be the reason to use `std::distance`.

Comment: just to add, from a strictly code readability, I tend to think **last - v.cbegin()** is not really clear about what should be the result.